# Chrome debugger stops at a function even without a DOM break point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, requestanimationframe

Hi I have a angular js application. And  when I run my application and hit F12 and open the debugger, for each and every page it continuously calling following function and stops there just like it has a break point.

Here is the stopping point

```
TagCanvas.NextFrameRAF = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(DrawCanvasRAF);
};
```

But this function doesn't have any break points.

Comment: Are there any other types of breakpoints set like DOM/XHR/Event: https://puu.sh/r9IQL/70a9ed27ef.png ?

Comment: no there are no any break points

Comment: There is "Pause on exception" button in source tab (Looks like road stop sign with pause icon on it), maybe it's on?

Comment: No "Pause on exception" is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a Request Animation Frame breakpoint set:

[image]

You can find that in dev tools on the Sources tab on the right-hand side under Event Listener Breakpoints > Animation.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Since the problem has been fixed. I would like to know why this  event is keep calling always even without doing anything?

Comment: @wOxxOm actually I didn't select these break points. don't know from where they were selected

Comment: @tarzanbappa: I don't understand that question...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean why this Request Animation event always getting called. Is something wrong in my application?

Comment: @tarzanbappa: No, it's perfectly standard for `requestAnimationFrame` to be called **really** often. It allows JavaScript code to schedule a callback that will happen immediately before the browser redraws the screen.